# How to show Contacts of Account according to hierarchy on parent and child VF page? Also need test class help

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, contact, hierarchy

my salesforce instance has a two level account hierarchy structure of Parent and child(ren). I would like to show a list of all contacts within the hierarchy. For example Parent A has two Children accounts Child 1 and Child 2. When I click on contacts for Parent A I want to see all the contacts from Parent A, Child 1, and Child 2. When I click on contacts for Child 2 I would like to see all the contacts from Parent A, Child 1, and Child 2. I've found a few examples and codes that are close. For example:
[How to show Contacts of Account according to hierarchy on VF page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205593/how-to-show-contacts-of-account-according-to-hierarchy-on-vf-page/205940#205940)
This shows the Parent and both children on the parent account page but when I look at a child account it only shows Parent Contacts and contacts from the current child account.

I found this post too: [HELP displaying related contacts of all accounts in hierarchy?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315938/help-displaying-related-contacts-of-all-accounts-in-hierarchy)
which will show contacts from the parent and all children on the child account page but doesn't show any contacts on the parent page.

Lastly - for extra credit - I would really enjoy being able to add an edit button to each contact row similar to this post - https://www.mstsolutions.com/technical/custom-related-list-using-visualforce-and-apex/. I've tried to make Frankenstein apex class but I've not been able to get anything to pass validation so it's not worth offering up my attempts. Appreciate any help you can provide.

VF Page:

```
    <apex:outputPanel id="cont">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
            <apex:repeat value="{! accountList }" var="a">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="{! a.Name + IF(NOT(ISBLANK(a.ParentId)), ' (child of ' + a.Parent.Name + ')', '') }">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! a.Contacts }" var="con" id="conlist" title="Contact">
                        <apex:column value="{!con.Name}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!con.Phone}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!con.Email}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

And Apex Class

```
public with sharing class AccountHierarchyController {
    public Account acc { get; private set; }
    public List<Account> accountList { get; private set; }
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller { get; private set; }
    
    public AccountHierarchyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        this.accountList = new List<Account>();
        
        Account baseAccount = [SELECT Id, 
                               ParentId, 
                               Name,
                               Parent.Name,
                               (SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Email from Contacts),
                               (SELECT Id, Name FROM ChildAccounts)
                               FROM Account 
                               WHERE Id = :acc.id];
        accountList.add(baseAccount);
        
        Account currentAccount = baseAccount;
 
        // Traverse the hierarchy upwards.
        while (currentAccount.ParentId != null) {
            currentAccount = [Select id, Name, ParentId, Parent.Name, (Select Id, Name, Phone, Email from Contacts) from Account where Id = :currentAccount.ParentId];
            accountList.add(currentAccount);
        }
        
        // Traverse the hierarchy downwards
        Set<Id> accountsToQuery = new Map<Id, Account>(baseAccount.ChildAccounts).keySet();
        while (accountsToQuery.size() > 0) {
            List<Account> thisLevelAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Parent.Name,
                                               (Select Id, Name, Phone, Email from Contacts),
                                               (SELECT Id, Name FROM ChildAccounts)
                                               FROM Account
                                               WHERE Id IN :accountsToQuery];
            accountsToQuery = new Set<Id>();
            
            for (Account a : thisLevelAccounts) {
                // Add this Account (with its Contacts) to the list.
                accountList.add(a);
                
                // Add this Account's children to the query for the next level.
                for (Account child : a.ChildAccounts) {
                    accountsToQuery.add(child.Id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

test class - currently 54% coverage :o(

```
@isTest
private class AccountHierarchyControllerTest {


   @isTest static void AccountHierarchyControllery(){    

       Account ac = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');   
       insert ac;
              
      //AccountNew is the Visualforce page created
       PageReference testPage = Page.contactrelatedlist; 
       Test.setCurrentPage(testPage);
       testPage.getParameters().put('Id', String.valueOf(ac.Id));
       
       ApexPages.StandardController sc = new  ApexPages.StandardController(ac);     
       AccountHierarchyController ext = new AccountHierarchyController(sc);         
        
       //System.debug(ext.AccountHierarchyController()); 
       List<Account> al = [Select Name from Account where Name LIKE '%test%' LIMIT 1];
       System.assertEquals(1, al.size());
 
    
   } 
  }
```

Original Post: [How to show Contacts of Account according to hierarchy on VF page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205593/how-to-show-contacts-of-account-according-to-hierarchy-on-vf-page/205940#205940)